# how can i add boot sector in ms dos image file when we are using windows os?

Tags: assembly, boot, bootloader

i found that there is a command in linux for adding boot sector to disk image as given:

```
dd count=2 seek=0 bs=512 if=..\source\bootload\bootload.bin of=.\mikeos.flp
```

but what is the similar command for windows option.

Comment: You are on windows 10 ?

Comment: You probably want `conv=notrunc`, otherwise why bother using `dd`?

Answer (score 1):

You can install [GNU core utils for Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin64/), you will get the original dd command but compiled for windows.